# Failed to resolve: floatingactionbutton-1.10.1 got error in androidx

Tags: android-studio

i got following error at Build Time

```
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find floatingactionbutton-1.10.1.aar (net.i2p.android.ext:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/i2p/android/ext/floatingactionbutton/1.10.1/floatingactionbutton-1.10.1.aar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Below is my dependancies

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation ("com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2") {exclude group: "com.android.support"}
implementation 'com.github.axet:android-library:1.32.20'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
implementation "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0"
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.axet.fbreader:library:0.1.14'
implementation 'com.github.axet:djvulibre:0.1.4'
implementation 'com.github.axet:pdfium:2.0.14'
implementation 'com.github.axet:k2pdfopt:0.1.6'
implementation('com.github.axet:wget:1.6.1') { exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json' }
assets('com.madgag.spongycastle:bctls-jdk15on:1.58.0.0') { exclude module: 'junit' }
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.0.0'
implementation files('libs/GenAsync.1.2.jar')
```

In dependencies, I already added androidx material.

Below is my FloatingButton XML Code

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

I didn't write any code on the fab button click event.

I got this problem when I transfer this project to another PC.

Also, This project completely works on the old PC but not on the new PC.
In the new PC, I made a new project & it works perfectly with the fab button.

I tried Invalidate Caches & Restart.
Downgrade Android Studio 4.1.1 to 4.1

Clean & rebuild project.

Also, Removed the fab button from XML but the same error exists.

I also tried the following dependency but the same error occurs.

```
implementation  'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
```

Guys, Please help me

Comment: did you add the mavenCentral() repository on your build.gradle?

Comment: yes, I added...